# ios4 sdk ipad - Can we put two VIEWS inside window?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios4

I want to place two views side by side like they did in the MAIL app for the ipad. Is this possible with `UINavigationController`?

I would like to place two `UINavigationController` side by side

Dont worry about the syntax I just want to know if it is possible

```
UINavigationConroller *left;  
UINavigationController *right;  

[WIndow addSubView: left];  
[WIndow addSubView:right];
```

Comment: For the iPad, it is a split view controller, not two separate controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIWindow inherits directly from UIView, so it is possible to add multiple objects to it, though if you add multiple view controllers then only one of them will receive rotation events.

The correct means to do a Mail-type presentation is to use a UISplitViewController, which automatically handles the transition between two view and one view mode. The Xcode template for a 'Split View-based Application' will even set you up so that you have an button to view the left tableview as a UIPopoverController if you're in portrait.

EDIT: example code, with a split view controller:

```
// a tiny little method to vend a new navigation controller; following Cocoa patterns, because it
// has 'new' in the name it vends an owning reference (ie, not autoreleased, retain count +1)
- (UINavigationController *)newController
{
    UITabBarController *tabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tabBar];
    [tabBar release];

    return navController;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // generate a split view controller
    UISplitViewController *splitView = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];

    // grab a couple of navigation controllers
    UINavigationController *navController1 = [self newController];
    UINavigationController *navController2 = [self newController];

    // add the navigation controllers to the split view controller
    splitView.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController1, navController2, nil];
    [navController1 release];
    [navController2 release];

    // and put the whole thing on screen
    [window addSubview:splitView.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: If I have two UINavigationController views and add them to the window; can I have them sit side by side? some how the views doesnt look like they load or taking up the entire screen.  I am NOT using a nib but adding them manually in code.

Comment: You really should use a UISplitViewController. I'll add an example to the answer, since it's difficult to format comments...